# How to disable IPv6 through cmd script

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

I don't want to manually uncheck the IPv6 checkbox in network connection.

I want to make a cmd logon script to disable IPv6 for a dozen of computers.

I have tried:

```
netsh interface teredo set state disable
netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled
netsh interface isatap set state disabled
```

But, it is not working.

Comment: You should only disable IPv6 on the interfaces in Windows. Completely disabling IPv6 on Windows can be done, but it breaks things since Windows uses it internally, and Microsoft will refuse support for such systems.

Comment: Sounds a lot like you're seeing the link local ipaddress output. Define 'not working'. Most people can't reach ipv6 anyway and disabling it isn't very useful in that case.

Comment: Thanks all. We want to disable it as we don't need it and we would like to prevent conflicts.